# The exe file generated by PyInstaller does not work when importing colour module

Tags: python, colors, pyinstaller

I am working over a project using `colour` library, using python 3.9 32 bit and pycharm is working, but when I convert it to exe using `pyinstaller` the exe does not work. To debug I created a simple program, the exe of this program does not work
my system is windows 10 64
converting command
pyinstaller simple_colour.py

```py
import colour
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel

class mainwindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        
        self.label = QLabel("Colour module is loaded")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)


app = QApplication([])
window = mainwindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Please paste the complete traceback, "*does not work*" does not help in understanding the issue.

Comment: Application Error The Exception Unknown Software Exception

Comment: That's not the traceback, package your app in console mode and then run it from the command line, you will see the complete error there, copy and paste that entirely.

Comment: when running it from the ommand it does not give any traceback error

Comment: I see, can you edit the question and include the `pyinstaller` command used to create the exe